# Understanding Python Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm seriously struggling to understand python recursion. We've been given a problem and I for the life of me cannot understand it.

**The Problem:** 
Write a python program that prints the solution to the game board supplied in a text area. The numbers in the text area created a game board. Example:

|1|4|2|3|6|1|1|2|

To win the game, you need to start at the beginning and end exactly on the finish.  You can only move the number in the cell, but you can move left or right as long as you stay on the board.

Discussion:
So from any given spot, you can go right or you can go left. So requirements are: 
1) If index is < 0 OR index is > board length -- Return game cannot be won
2) If Cell Value is Zero , game ends unless it is the last cell on the board
3) Each Cell may only be visited once.

What I have so far:

```
def playGame(_currentIndex):
    _path.append(_currentIndex)
    print("Current Path --> ")
    print(_path)
    _currentIndex=_gameBoard[_currentIndex]
    win = False
    while win == False:
        #Check Can win from current position directly?
        if _currentIndex-1 or _currentIndex+1 == end:
            print("Game can be won directly from current position!")
            print(_path)
            return True
        #Check for Loss:
        #Index Too High or Too Low
        if _currentIndex < 0 or _currentIndex > end:
            print("Game cannot be won")
            exit(code = 0)
        #Cell Value of Zero
        elif _gameBoard[_currentIndex] == 0:
            #If Cell Value Zero and Is Last Cell
            if _currentIndex == end:
                print("Game won!")
                print(_path)
                win = True
            else:
                print("Game cannot be won")
                exit(code=0)
        #Cell has been visited before
        elif (_currentIndex in _path):
            print("Game cannot be won")
            exit(code = 0)
        elif (playGame(-(_currentIndex))) or (playGame(-(_currentIndex))):
            win = True
        else:
            win = False
```

I'm getting a recursion depth exceeded using a game board of [1,1] and cannot figure out why?

EDIT --- So I understand recursion if its only doing one thing, for example:

```
def rec(int):
    if int == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        num = int + (int - 1)
        print(num)
        rec(int - 1)


rec(3)
```

This works fine and prints out:
5
3
1

But what if I wanted to do this by adding or subtracting until int == 0 or int == 10?

Comment: What is that line close to the end? `elif (playGame(-(_currentIndex))) or (playGame(-(_currentIndex))):`

Comment: Thats basically moving the index to the left or to the right.  The psuedo code we were given is:  I "can win" the game from the current position IF I "can win" to the right OR i "can win" to the left.
def canWin( ...current... ):
    # code to return True or False if you can win or can't win directly goes here
    if canWin(...left…) or canWin(...right…):
        return True
    else
        return False

Comment: `if _currentIndex-1 or _currentIndex+1 == end:` is not correct. I'm not sure what you intend there, maybe `if _currentIndex-1 == end or _currentIndex+1 == end:`?

Comment: @Fxguy1 Read closely, you are testing `if X or X`.

Comment: In general, `while variable == False:` is poor style. It's better to use `while True:`, and then use `break` when you want to stop the loop.

Comment: So thinking more about this, the base case would be that the path length is equal to the game board length and the game still hasnt been won. Not sure how to define that thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first solution**

Given an input puzzle, `q`,

1. If current index `i` is out of bounds or has been seen before in `mem` (base case), return `False`
2. Otherwise (inductive) `i` is *in* bounds and has *not* been seen before. If `i` is equal to the last index, return the solution, `sln`
3. Otherwise (inductive) `i` is *in* bounds, has *not* been seen before, and is *not* the final index. Append `i` to `mem` and `sln` and recursively attempt to solve `i+q[i]` **or** `i-q[i]`

Explanation above corresponds with numbered comments below -

```py
def solve(q, i=0, mem=set(), sln=()):
  if i in mem or i<0 or i>=len(q):  #1
    return False
  elif i == len(q)-1:               #2
    return (*sln, i)
  else:                             #3
    return \
      solve(q, i+q[i], mem|{i}, (*sln, i)) \
    or \
      solve(q, i-q[i], mem|{i}, (*sln, i))
```

```py
puzzle = [1,4,2,3,6,1,1,2]

print(solve(puzzle))
```

```py
(0, 1, 5, 6, 7)
```

The answer is the sequence of indices to reach the final index -

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7     <-- index
[1,4,2,3,6,1,1,2]    <-- puzzle
 ^ ^       ^ ^ ^     <-- (0, 1, 5, 6, 7)
```

It is necessary to use `mem` to avoid checking the same indices more than once. Ie, certain input puzzles may cause the solver to go into an infinite loop. If we have already visited index `i` once before, we know it's a dead-end and so we return `False`

```py
solve([3,0,1,1,1,0,3])
```

```py
False
```

In this example, we see the solution bounce around then finally land on the last index -

```py
solve([3,6,1,2,4,0,3,1,0,9])
```

```py
(0, 3, 1, 7, 6, 9)
```

---

**all solutions**

The program above finds only the first solution to the puzzle. Generators allow us to make a tiny modification to the program above and have it find *all* solutions -

```py
def solve(q, i=0, mem=set(), sln=()):
  if i in mem or i<0 or i>=len(q):
    return                                   # <- dead-end; backtrack
  elif i == len(q)-1:
    yield (*sln, i)                          # <- found solution    
  else:
    yield from \                             # <- hop right
      solve(q, i+q[i], mem|{i}, (*sln, i))
    yield from \                             # <- hop left
      solve(q, i-q[i], mem|{i}, (*sln, i))

puzzle = [1,4,2,3,6,1,1,2]

print(list(solve(puzzle)))
```

```py
[(0, 1, 5, 6, 7)]
```

We have create the list of all possible solutions. For this particular puzzle, we now know that there are no other possibilities to solve it. However, let's look at the puzzle that was just posted by [user11302163](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66271932/633183) -

```py
puzzle = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

for sln in solve(puzzle):
  print(sln)
```

```py
(0, 10, 1, 9, 16)
(0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 13, 14, 16)
(0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 13, 14, 12, 11, 16)
(0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 13, 12, 11, 16)
(0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 11, 16)
```

Generators are particularly good at solving this kind of problem. For example, maybe we want to find the first solution that is 10 steps or more -

```py
for sln in solve(puzzle):
  if len(sln) >= 10:
    print(sln)
    break
```

```py
(0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 13, 14, 12, 11, 16)
```

Generators give the caller control, allowing us pause/stop the computation as soon as we are satisfied with a particular result. At this point, no other solutions will be attempted, potentially saving many wasted computations.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting it in one direction, as well as steps #1 and #2 above, it was the concept of #3 or bouncing back and forth that I was struggling with!

Answer (score 2):

Recursion depth error occur when there is no base case for a specific state. This is often a telltale sign that you either aren't handling all base cases, or that your base case is not adequate.

I can't tell you what case you are not capturing since I don't have the game board data; however, it means that you are never returning out of the function which means that you are stuck in that while loop.

Comment: Shon - The point is that this work regardless of the game board data. It is supposed to work regardless of where the game starts either. So I'm still struggling with the whole idea of base case. I "think" the base case is from the current position, will going right or going left win the game?

Comment: The base case if when your current index is the last possible index, if I understood your game properly. You win when you reach the second 2 correct? `|1|4|2|3|6|1|1|2| <- here`. I think the main problem with your code is that several `if`s are not properly written.

Comment: That is correct. If _currentIndex == last index then game is won. Otherwise the game cannot be won. So how do I work backwards from there? Basically If _currentIndex != last index then check if moving right or moving left works, then repeat.

Comment: @Fxguy1 My point wasn't that your function should only handle a specific board. It was that without knowing what data you pass into the function that triggers the recursion depth error, I cannot tell you what base case is NOT handled.